# Accessing server-side data

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, apache-flex

I am a Flex developer and now I have started learning the fundamentals of iOS, Objective-C, and accessing server-side data. Most of the Flex projects I do are mainly in accessing server-side data with Flex from .Net, Python, and Java since we all know data access in Flex is possible only via 3 ways: Http, Web-service, and Remote Object. Out of these 3, Remote Object is the most reliable, fast and handy.

1. My Question is, do we have remote object concept in iOS? I mean is there any interface (like blaze DS, weborb) available on the market for serializing/deserializing Objective-C object type to C#, Java, and python or vice versa?
2. What is the best way to communicate in PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906915/how-do-i-control-access-to-my-server-side-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options. Some require using an external library which isn't in the base SDK. You can check stuff like: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/ 
I usually prefer working with PHP and a very simple REST API, but of-course it depends on what you're building and what your requirements are.

Comment: thanks a lot I think reference is helpful for new developer like me. 
My requirement is very simple , starting with simple CRUD from my iphone application , post data to PHP page in turn update my MYSql.

Comment: Are you familiar with REST API? The only thing you'll probably need to add that way is a JSON library, which is quite simple. It's very simple.

Comment: JSON/REST I have some experience in JSON ie populating a HTML menu from JSON data through javascript. REST Im not familiar can you let me know which is best for Iphone and their difference.

Comment: You just send your request through the url. For example the app goes to www.yoursite.com&query=toFind, the server will output a JSON with the data, and the app will choose how to display it

Answer (score 1):

With Adobe's work to get AIR running on iOS I can say that WebORB for Java, .NET or PHP can be used to "easily" connect your Flex application running on iOS to a .NET, Java or PHP backend enabling you to do remoting and messaging. Soon, WebORB will support native iOS (Objective C).